# How do we convert a Python dictionary to a .txt file (with a format)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

For an example, if i have a dictionary in python that looks like:

```
{'John': ['boy, 'american'], 'Jane': ['girl', 'canadian']}.
```

how do we store it in .txt file as follows:

**sample.txt**

```
John
boy
american

Jane
girl
canadian
```

Comment: What have you tried? #WriteMyCodeForMe

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {'John': ['boy', 'american'], 'Jane': ['girl', 'canadian']}

with open('sample.txt', 'w') as f:
    for k, v in d.items():
        # write name
        f.write("{}\n".format(k))
        
        # write attributes of name
        for elem in v:
            f.write("{}\n".format(elem))

        # write new line
        f.write("\n")
```

Answer (score -1):

Yeah I found this online. Hopefully it helps.

[image]

Comment: Just a suggestion, rather than pasting the link of an image (from which nobody can't copy if needed) you could've posted the code itself which would be helpful for OP

Comment: this doesn't store the dict in the format of new lines, as requested, but saves it with apostrophes and braces